# Static library: hiding private members from header file

Tags: c++, class, static-libraries, header-files, private-members

I wish to compile part of my code as a static library to include in other project. Of course I'll have to distribute the compiled library and an header file containing the class declaration and the public members, but I don't know if it's possible to move all private members and declarations to a place different than the header file.

Example:

In the project.h file:

```
class MyClass
{
public: 
  MyClass();
  void Give_me_an_input(int);
  int Get_your_output();

private:
  int a, b;
  int MySecretAlgorithm();
};
```

In the .cpp file:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  a = 1; 
  b = 0;
}

void MyClass::Give_me_an_input(int c)
{
  b = c;
}

int MyClass::Get_your_output()
{
  return MySecretAlgorithm();
}

int MyClass::MySecretAlgorithm()
{
  return (a + b);
}
```

Is there a way to move all private members `int a, b;` and `int MySecretAlgorithm();` to a place different than the header file?

Comment: No, because they are required for the class definition. But you could re-implement the class using e.g. the *pimpl idiom* (at the cost of some indirection.)

Comment: Do you care if others can see only the declaration? You can declare it with some dummy unmeaningful name. Then, in the `cpp` file, implement it. In your secret file, create a pointer to this function, with a meaningful name

Comment: if you want to hide info from whoever uses this library, you can consider using something like a `vector<void*>` and casting the elements as needed. It wouldn't be pretty, though.

Comment: +1 for the pimpl idiom

Comment: Why are you looking to do that? What is the motivation/goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer to implementation idiom can be used in such a scenario, commonly referred to as [*pimpl*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl).
The basic idea is to take the implementation details out of the declaration
and simply have an opaque pointer to the implementation details.

`std::unique_ptr` is used in the the following example; but you could of course just use normal pointers.

```
// my_class declaration unit.
class my_class {
private:
   class impl;
   unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;

public:

};

// my_class implementation unit
class my_class::impl {
   int whatever;
   int whenever;
};

my_class::my_class(): pimpl( new impl )
{
}
```

Comment: Ugh - I forgot about doing this way - which is really the best way.

Comment: However, for a statically linked library it doesn't really make sense to hide the implementation details at all, since there are no ABI concern thus very little to nothing to gain from it.

Answer (score 2):

Over the years I've seen some hacks to do this, but I don't think they are worth it.  If your library is reasonably 'chunky' (ie: no method is being called a billion times a microsecond); and you can re-write chunks of your code...

You might consider making all the public stuff an abstract class (all virtual = 0) and then deriving your concrete classes from it.

Down sides of this:
- All your public calls become virtual (some optimizations can bypass this, but not often).
- You can't 'new up' your classes anymore, you'll need to implement a factory pattern.

The problem with any of the other hacks I'm familiar with is that they basically declare the methods in one set of headers, and then redeclare the same things with the 'real' implementation in private headers - depending on the linker to match up the names.  A couple problems here are:

- Maintaining this mess sucks.  You can't use an #ifdef because it sounds like you want to physically hide your implementation. So you have dual maintaining, or a build step that generates your public headers.
- Can only be used via pointer.  You have to play games making constructors private and still have a factory because the compiler won't generate structs of the right size if you let the client gen it by value (or even with new).
- Finally, I once saw a hack where the programmer tried to declare a byte array in the private area of the 'public' class so that the client code could still declare by value or 'new' it themselves.  This suffers all the previous problems, plus you probably don't want to have to 'know' the size of the structs since they depend on packing and alignment.  Your 'build step' would more or less have to have a runtime component that used sizeof() - and now you have a versioning problem if you want to change the size of the struct/class.