# header file for exporting class from shared library

Tags: c++, export, shared-libraries, header-files

I have built a shared lib (.so) that contains several classes. I now need to create the header file to use to import those classes into another app. Some of the exported classes have private data/functions. Do those need to be included in that header file?

eg:

orig.h (header used to build the lib)

```
#ifndef __MYLIB__
#define __MYLIB__

// system includes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

namespace myspace{
// my includes
#include "..."

#ifndef EXPORT_API
#define EXPORT_API   __attribute__((__visability__("default")))
#endif

class EXPORT_API MyClass1 {
public:
   MyClass1();
   virtual ~MyClass1();

public:
    ...        // public members 

protected:
   ...        // protected members

private:     // private members
   ...       // these should not be visible outside of the lib


};
} //namespace
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif  // __MYLIB__
```

This builds okay.

exp.h used by users of the lib to build their app

```
#ifndef __MYLIB__
#define __MYLIB__

// system includes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

namespace myspace{

class  MyClass1 {
public:
   MyClass1();
   virtual ~MyClass1();

public:
    ...        // public members 

protected:
   ...        // protected members

// no private members listed here.

};
} //namespace
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif //__MYLIB__
```

In my userapp.h:

```
#ifndef __MYUSER__
#endif
#include <...> //system includes

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "exp.h"

//derived class
class MyClass2 : public MyClass1 {
public:
   MyClass2();
   ~virtual MyClass2();

public:
  // derived class members
  myclass2_func();

  int   m_myclass2int;
};
```

In main.cpp:
#include "userapp.h"

```
using myspace;
int main(int *argc, char** argv){

MyClass2   theClass;

// make member calls to theClass
theClass.myclass2_func();
theClass.m_myclass2int = 0;

return 0;
}
```

This also builds okay.

But when I debug userapp, memory gets corrupted, most likely from bad pointers. This is typically when I step through derived class functions (eg. myclass2_func), either I get a segmentation fault (memory access violation) or sometimes gdb itself crashes (when trying to display values). I am guessing that this has to do with the private section, inside the lib, that I didn't specify in exp.h.

So back to the original question: do those private sections need to be included in the import header file?

TIA

ken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static library: hiding private members from header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416262/static-library-hiding-private-members-from-header-file)

Comment: Not really (well, maybe). This says that I can't just remove the private section from the import lib header. OK, but with the pimpl method, that causes another bigger problem: If a private member function needs to access a (virtual) function in the public section, in particular obtaining an address to a function in a derived class, the compiler will probably gripe about accessing non-static member function in derived class similar to this problem https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/275610/ .

Comment: You need to use the same header file for building the library as you do for linking to it. Define a macro in your library's project file. e.g. BUILD_LIB and use it with #ifdef in the header to choose how you define EXPORT_API. Define a macro in your library's project file. e.g. BUILD_LIB and use it with #ifdef in the header to choose how you define EXPORT_API. For linking, you can #def it as declspec(dllimport) and for building, declspec(dllexport).